# About a simple linked list to set struct pointer correctly

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, singly-linked-list

This code creates a dynamic linked list which also memory allocate and free correctly, but there is a small step I'm quite puzzled. It seems it didn't set the first struct pointer `start->next` to the next, which I think it should. But when I try to run it, it works well. Then I try to add `start->next=next;` it also works well. Please help me to check and tell me why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct island {
    char *name;
    char *opens;
    char *closes;
    struct island *next;
} island;

island* create(char *name) {
    island *i = malloc(sizeof(island));
    i->name = strdup(name);
    i->opens = "09:00";
    i->closes = "17:00";
    i->next = NULL;
    return i;
}

void display(island *start) {
    island *i = start;
    for (; i != NULL; i = i->next) {
        printf("Name: %s open: %s-%s\n", i->name, i->opens, i->closes);
    }
}

void release(island *start) {
    island *i = start;
    island *next = NULL;
    for (; i != NULL; i = next) {
        next = i->next;
        free(i->name);
        free(i);
    }
}

int main() {

    island *start = NULL;
    island *i = NULL;
    island *next = NULL;
    char name[80];
    for (; fgets(name, 80, stdin) != NULL; i = next) {
        next = create(name);
        if (start == NULL)
            start = next;  //change this line to {start = next;start->next=next;} also works.
        if (i != NULL)
            i->next = next;
    }

    display(start);
    release(start);

    return 0;
}
```

I want to exactly what happened inside so I draw this to help myself understand.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ways are the "same", the only differences in them is that in the second way ({start = next;start->next=next;}) you are setting the 'next' to point to the same node (something that not makes sense) in the first iteration, anyways this doesn't matter because in the next iteration it will be overwritten by this sentence: "i->next = next;" (remember that 'i' points to the 'next' node from the previous iteration.

To clarify this further:

Assuming the first scenery where you just assign only "start = next;"

1st loop:

- 'start' is NULL so its assigned the pointer to the recently created node. 'start->next' is NULL.
- if (i != NULL) evaluates to false only in this first iteration.
- 'i' is assigned to point to 'next'

2nd loop:

- 'start' is not NULL so this step is skipped.
- 'i' points to the lasted created node in the previous iteration (next), so "i->next = next;" is executed always from this iteration to the last. Is in this step when you would overwrite the previously holded value (start->next=next)

Comment: Exactly. I already figured it out. Now I know the pointer magic which let you manipulate these puppies so freely which is just awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what your question is, but there is a huge logic error in main. In the for(;fgets(... loop you aren't maintaining a good head of the list. It should read more like

```
for(;fgets(...);...); {
   island *temp=create (name);
   if(temp==NULL) exit(1);
   if(start==NULL) start=temp;
   else {
      temp->next=start;
      start=temp; }
   }
```